# corda - sort based on value in specific order

Tags: sorting, corda

we have a use case wherein i need to sort states based on value. Say i have column 'Occupation' and it has values 'Doctor', "Engineer', "Artist'. I need to sort all states , such that all states that have  'Doctors' should come first  , followed by the others. Can this be achieved ? Appreciate any help. Thanks.

something like below.
SELECT * from  customer
ORDER BY CASE WHEN occupation = 'Doctor' THEN 1
ELSE 2 END

i checked the vault query link in r3 docs, but could not find anything related to this.